# Is the HTML5 WebSockets protocol lossless?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Considering it uses TCP/IP, I'm guessing it is, but I'm not well enough versed in the spec (or the reading thereof) to know for sure. As an aside, does it also ensure they are delivered and read in the correct order?

The question derives from a need in an HTML5 games library I'm writing, but I suppose that's beside the point.

Comment: What do you mean by lossless? That messages (packets) are guaranteed to be delivered?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Yes. I'm not sure of any guarantee that TCP/IP packets are sent *whole*, but that is just my lack of knowledge. Sorry for the lack of specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WebSockets are based on TCP, the messages you send are guaranteed to be received (or an error will be raised).

Messages sent *in sequence through the same (websocket) connection by the same client* are received in order (think of it as writing everything to a file and reading the same afterwards), but there is no guarantee about the order in which messages will come from  *different connections established by the same client* or *connections established by different clients*, even if you knew the order in which they were sent.

The usual approach in the latter scenario is embedding a timestamp in each message, so that you can reconstruct the correct temporal sequence on the server.

As an aside, if your server processes requests using threads, then two messages could be processed out of order even if received in order (but this is another story).

Comment: Thank you for the complete and prompt answer. :)

Comment: The order of messages is guaranteed between a pair of WebSocket peers. The receiving peer will get a sequence of WebSocket messages exactly as sent.

Comment: @oberstet it is stated in the footnote above. Please tell me if you think it's not clear enough and I will rephrase the sentence

Comment: At least, I think it can be easily misunderstood, since the most common use of WebSocket involves a _single_ WebSocket connection, and messages on a single WebSocket connection are always ordered (in both directions). No timestamps are needed. The scenario where messages are sent over different WebSocket connection, at extreme a new WebSocket connection per message, are rare.

Comment: Yes, great - much clearer IMHO.

However, the last sentence doesn't apply in general (what do you mean with request?). WebSocket servers work differently from HTTP servers. Even a WebSocket server that uses a thread-per-connection policy will process WebSocket messages on a single connection in order. I don't know a single WebSocket server that would schedule incoming WS messages to a pool of thread with "no stickyness". Doesn't make a lot of sense. This is different from HTTP, where each request/response exchange is semantically separate already, and hence may be scheduled independently ..